# In MySQL, what's the most efficient way to query an entire table in chunks?

Tags: mysql, performance, limits, pagination

If I have a table `User` is it faster to do something like:

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 10000`

(With each subsequent query using the previous last row's id as the param)

Or to use a LIMIT with an offset, like this:

`SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id LIMIT ?, 10000`

(With total number of records retrieved so far being the offset).

As an additional complication, what if I wanted to perform a similar query based on a linking table join? Like say a `user` could belong to multiple roles, so I wanted a query like

`SELECT u.*
 FROM user u
 INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.user_id = u.id
 WHERE ur.role_name IN ('Admin', 'SuperUser', 'etc.')
 LIMIT ?, 10000`

Does a join affect the decision as to which style query is preferred?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`OFFSET` is *very bad*.  Instead of processing the data in Order(N) time, it will take Order(N*N).  This is because of the effort to skip past the "offset" rows.

Instead "remember where you left off".  I go into details about such in these two blogs:

- Pagination via OFFSET is bad:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination (It gives details on "left off" as a good alternative)
- How to delete lots of rows via chunking:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig . You need to adapt it from `DELETE` to what you are doing.  It also gives tips on how to walk through the `PRIMARY KEY` to efficiently discover the next 'chunk'.

These tips apply to all versions of MySQL.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the LIMIT clause with an offset would result in a re-read through all previous rows for each iteration.

Comment: This is really correct answer.